# Excel VBA - save worksheet to new file without formulas

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Need some assistance to complete this VBA code, I've taken it as far as my limited knowledge will get me.

Scenario: I have a master workbook which pulls in data from two other spreadsheets exported from a program (to save copy/pasting), I then need to export only 1 sheet and save as a new file and the VBA code below does the job perfectly.

```
Sub savesheet2()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
ActiveSheet.Select
ActiveSheet.Copy
ThisFile = Range("A2").Text
Dim fileName As String
fileName = "C:\INTERNAL\ACCOUNTS\" & ThisFile
ActiveSheet.SaveAs fileName:=fileName, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

What I need to include is coding to remove the formulas (export values only) and retain conditional formating from the masterwork book.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: When I don't know the correct VBA code needed to complete an action I use the Macro Recorder in Excel.  It lets you perform a series of actions manually and generates the code needed to do the same steps programmatically.  From this code I can usually figure out what I need to write the finished product.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing that comes to mind is to just replace every cell by its value.

```
For Each c In Cells
    c = c.Value
Next c
```

If you have a ton of cells, this might take some time.

Alternatively, you can select the entire sheet and paste-special the values:

```
Cells.Copy
Cells.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

Neither of these should change any conditional formatting.

Answer (score 0):

```
  Public Sub convertir_fichero(fichero_origen As String)

 Dim nuevo_libro As Workbook
 Dim indice As Integer
 Dim Ruta_Salida As String

 Set nuevo_libro = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet)


 Application.CalculateBeforeSave = False
 Application.DisplayAlerts = False

 Workbooks(fichero_origen).Activate
 Ruta_Salida = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\Salida_aux.xlsx"

 nuevo_libro.SaveAs Ruta_Salida, AccessMode:=xlExclusive, ConflictResolution:=Excel.XlSaveConflictResolution.xlLocalSessionChanges

 For indice = 1 To Workbooks(fichero_origen).Worksheets.Count
    Dim nombre_hoja As String

    nombre_hoja = Workbooks(fichero_origen).Worksheets(indice).Name

    nuevo_libro.ActiveSheet.Name = nombre_hoja

    Workbooks(fichero_origen).Worksheets(nombre_hoja).Activate

    If Workbooks(fichero_origen).Worksheets(nombre_hoja).FilterMode = True Then
       Workbooks(fichero_origen).Worksheets(nombre_hoja).AutoFilter.ShowAllData
    End If
    Cells.Select
    Selection.Copy
    'After:=ActiveSheet
    nuevo_libro.Sheets(nombre_hoja).Activate
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

    'formato
    Workbooks(fichero_origen).Worksheets(nombre_hoja).Activate
    Cells.Select
    Selection.Copy
    nuevo_libro.Sheets(nombre_hoja).Activate
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
        SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    If ((indice Mod 5) = 0) Then
      nuevo_libro.SaveAs Ruta_Salida, AccessMode:=xlExclusive, ConflictResolution:=Excel.XlSaveConflictResolution.xlLocalSessionChanges
    End If
    If (indice < Workbooks(fichero_origen).Worksheets.Count) Then
      nuevo_libro.Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
    End If
 Next indice

  nuevo_libro.SaveAs Ruta_Salida, AccessMode:=xlExclusive, ConflictResolution:=Excel.XlSaveConflictResolution.xlLocalSessionChanges
End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Can you explain what your VBA does?